# How execute Sonar test unit

Tags: junit, sonarqube

My doubt are how to order executing Sonar methods inside test class, because sometimes i have seen some problem with times(XXX). Somebody knows how to order methods for Sonar??
THX

Comment: We have sometimes similar issues with static context of SUT. You could  call reset() for mocks or re-init static context before tests starts

Comment: I´m thinking in this solution but I can't understand why Sonar executes different order.

Comment: I think the intention of unit tests that they should run correctly in any order. As well there is no way to specify order for JUnit tests, at least I don't know

Comment: I think that you have reason. THX